# HTML/PHP adding multiple textfields and put it all together into 1 string

Tags: php, html, input

I am creating a form where a user can input certain information.
The default state looks as following;

```
<div class="options">
<input type="text" name="option[]" />
<input type="text" name="content[]" />
</div>
```

Now, by clicking a button ADD, I will add two new fields with the same name so the state is as follows;

```
    <div class="options">
    <input type="text" name="option[]" />
    <input type="text" name="content[]" />
    <input type="text" name="option[]" />
    <input type="text" name="content[]" />
    </div>
```

Then, I want PHP to eventually create a string as below;

```
valueOfFirstOption:valueOfFirstContent,valueOfSecondOption:valueOfSecondContent
```

And so on, and so on. Theoretically I should be able to add an infinite amount of input fields.

Is this possible what I am trying to achieve? Or should I be adding unique names to the input fields?

Any tips or hints how I should be going? Or somebody got a tutorial/example code for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is jQuery an option (for adding additional fields)?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit nicer if you could set indexes in the name when you add the extra elements.

```
<div class="options">
  <input type="text" name="data[0][option]" />
  <input type="text" name="data[0][content]" />
  <input type="text" name="data[1][option]" />
  <input type="text" name="data[1][content]" />
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="addSet(); return false;">Add</a>
<script>
    var addSet = function() {
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('options')[0];
        var numInputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var numSets = numInputs/2;
        var nextIndex = numSets;

        var newOption = document.createElement('input');
        newOption.name = 'data[' + nextIndex + '][option]';
        container.appendChild(newOption);

        var newContent = document.createElement('input');
        newContent.name = 'data[' + nextIndex + '][content]';
        container.appendChild(newContent);
    }
</script>
```

Then when you receive the POST, you can just loop through data and process the duplets

```
$pieces = array();

foreach ($_POST['data'] as $set)
    $pieces = $set['option'] . ':' . $set['content'];
}

// or
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['data']); $i++) {
    $pieces[] = $_POST['data'][$i]['option'] . ':' . $_POST['data'][$i]['content'];
}

// then
$compiledString = implode(",", $pieces);
```